# return an mp3 file as Json object

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, httpresponse

I have an application that converts the input text into speech , what I want to do is to connect between my web service and the application android , the mp3 files is in FTP server , so I want when the user input a text , so this text will be send to the service then by algorithm it will concatenate the right voice files in order to return it into the application and the user then can listen to it , I want to use the REST web services and I want to get the mp3 files using JSON , how can I return this mp3 file as JSON object to the application then to parser it ?????

Comment: You can return a JSON object that contains a link to the mp3 file on the server but an mp3 file cannot be be directly converted to JSON.

Comment: I want to return the mp3 file itself , not just the link of it , because I want to make a features that the user can store this files in his application (device ) , so he can run this files offline without need an internet .

Comment: JSON and MP3 are not compatible with one another. If you want to return JSON to provide details about the MP3 being returned, you may do so and include the link to the actual MP3 with it. Then you can download the MP3 to the device.

Comment: @NoorAlaref: why cannot you run a mp3 offline?

Comment: This features as known as an ungly development :) by the way if you can transmit a text data you can send a binary data too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no benefit in returning the mp3 as json, or returning json with a link to the mp3.

Base64 adds a 4/3 size increase and downloading mp3 is easier (does not require decoding base64)

Answer (score 1):

You can Base64 encode the MP3. That would be plain text and thus could be send as a JSON string.

Of course the client would need to have knowledge about how do decode the Base64 encoded bytes.